# Double MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently developing an app with a vote feature. I would like people not to sign in and make it simple, so I collect the IP after every vote. With this feature the IP will never vote on the same thing again.

But I find it hard to `SELECT` a voting, that hasn't been voting by the IP. I've tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE state = '-1' 
  AND id != (SELECT message_id FROM log WHERE ip = '$ip')
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: What difficulty did you encounter when using this method?

Comment: Please post schema, and clarify the goal of this query.  Also, IP is a very poor mechanism for identity.  Please reconsider using it.

Comment: Filtering by IP will hose any users who share a common NAT gateway, which is pretty much ALL mobile users for any given provider, some ISPs, etc...

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you can use a cookie instead of the IP

Comment: Is it then possible to get a unique ID of an iPhone/iPod?

Comment: @RoboForm: of course it is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly - this query should help you:

```
SELECT messages.* FROM messages 
LEFT JOIN log ON log.message_id = messages.id AND log.ip = '$ip'
WHERE state = '-1' AND log.ip IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE state = '-1' 
  AND id NOT IN (SELECT message_id FROM log WHERE ip = '$ip')
```

will do what you say, but I am quite positive it will not do what you want: E.g. it will allow only one mobile user of a typical cell tower to vote, but will allow him to vote again, after he has lost signal and regathered it at an other location.

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM messages " .
"WHERE state = '-1' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM log WHERE log.message_id = messages.id  ". 
"AND ip = '" . $ip . "')";
```

A (NOT) EXISTS is usually faster than a IN expression

Comment: `A (NOT) EXISTS is usually faster than a IN expression` --- who told you so? It depends on a **lot** of factors